# Replacement into a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have the following polynomials:

```
pol = {x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^7, x + 2 x^5 + 4 x^6, 3 x^6 + 2 x^9};
```

and following list

```
val = {{2, 3}, {4}, {7, 8}};
```

both `pol` and `val` has length of 3 and they should be looked as one-to-one. Now I want to replace `val[[1]]` into `pol[[1]]` for each value and so on and so forth. I did:

```
pol /. x -> val
```

but this simply takes all values in `val` and replace them, but I want this to be one to one meaning `{2, 3}` shall only be replaces in `x^2 + 2 x^3 + 4 x^7` then `{4}` must be replaced in `x + 2 x^5 + 4 x^6` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MapThread[# /. x -> #2 &, {pol, val}]
```

> {{532, 8811}, {18436}, {81060161, 269221888}}

Also

```
# /. x -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{pol, val}]
```

> {{532, 8811}, {18436}, {81060161, 269221888}}